# How to set "C++ Standard Library Type" to "static" in Xcode 4?

Tags: sqlite, xcode4

I have an Xcode 3.2 project (sqlite3 with icu) that builds correctly, and I'm trying to recreate it in Xcode 4. I'm getting link errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for icu_48::SortKeyByteSinkin libicui18n.a(ucol.ao)
      ...
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libicui18n.a(uregex.ao)
      ...
```

I had this once before, with Xcode 3.2. I it then by changing build setting `Linking-> C++ Standard Library Type` to `static` (the default is `dynamic`). If I understand the docs correctly, the actual flag is `STANDARD_C_PLUS_PLUS_LIBRARY_TYPE`.

**But I can't find that setting in Xcode 4!**

**EDIT**

The main module (sqlite3) is C, but the ICU library is C++, presumably with C declarations. I can build `sqlite3` fine by itself, it's when I need to link in the ICU library that the trouble starts.

Answer (score 0):

Your app may be C but it looks like libicui18n includes C++.

What happens if you rename your `main.m` to `main.mm`? That should cause it to be linked against the standard C++ library.

Comment: My mistake (I corrected the question), but I don't know what you mean about `main.m`--there aren't any `.m` files in this project, only `.c`.

Comment: Sorry. Assumed Objective C since you were using Xcode. In that case, rename `main.c` to `main.cc`? You want to force Xcode to use `g++`/`clang++` to do the link and it seems to trigger this based on the suffix of `main`. If you don't have a `main.c`, I figure there must be some other setting in Xcode that sets this but I'm not sure what it is.